# Visual Studio 2010 Intellisense throwing false errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've been writing a 2D game engine for about two years now, recently intellisense has been throwing false errors. The code compiles, links and runs just fine but there will be upwards of 70 "errors" reported by intellisense:

[image: Error list window showing false intellisense errors]

I tried deleting the SQL file for both the test project and the library generator project but the errors stopped for one, and only one, build while the intellisense database was rebuilt.

Even though it is not detrimental or stopping me from coding it's quite annoying to have to scroll all the way to the bottom to find the real error(s) when there is one.

Comment: This is a configuration problem, clearly the IS parser isn't using the same settings as the compiler.  Why this is so is entirely unguessable from the question.  Be sure to use the Project + Properties window to change project settings for things like C/C++, Preprocessor, Preprocessor Definitions and C/C++, General, Additional Include Directories.  Avoid hacking the environment in a prebuild event, makefiles or anything that affects the compiler at build time but not edit time.

Comment: @HansPassant The only thing I can think of is the use of relative paths to the include, reference and lib directories for Allegro: `\My_Games\3rdPartyTools\Allegro\4.2\msvc10\include` (replace `lib` for `include` for reference and lib directories) because sometimes I move from one machine to another and the absolute paths are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

It indeed was a configuration problem. Intellisense does not like relative paths. I added entries in the VC++ Directory listings that were absolute in addition to the relative paths and all is well.