# Ide posts error, though program runs

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I've got some simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
using namespace std;

template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
auto WhichParametr(unsigned int n, Arg arg, Args... args) -> boost::variant < Arg, Args... > {
    if (n != 1)
        return WhichParametr(n - 1, args...);
    return arg;
}

template <typename T>
T WhichParametr(unsigned int n, T arg){
    return arg;
}

int main(){
    cout << WhichParametr(4, 1, 2, '3', "foo");
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

WhichParametr() function returns n parametr that was given ( WhichParametr(1, 2, 3) returns 2 ).
My IDE Visual Studio 2013 says there is no overload that matches the argument list, tough program runs fine. Is there something in that code that I shouldn't use or is this just stupid IDE? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's stupid Intellisense. It's not aligned with the c++11 support of the compiler itself.

See also

- [Visual Studio 2010 Intellisense throwing false errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719527/visual-studio-2010-intellisense-throwing-false-errors)
- [Is there a way to suppress Intellisense errors when using C++11 features specific to November 2012 CTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713391/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-intellisense-errors-when-using-c11-features-specifi)

Comment: Thanks! Now I now it's safe to use